# Frame number equalling number -- Health Bar

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a bar where it is full on frame 1, then empty on frame 100, and I've made it into a shape tween. I want to create a code where when I press a certain button, it depletes the bar, so the frame goes from 1 until it reaches 100 as long as a certain button is held.

I was thinking of a way to do this, but it seems impossible.

```
var maxHP:int = 100;
var currentHP:int = maxHP;
var percentHP:Number = currentHP / maxHP;
```

I would like to have the percentHP var equal the bar, so as it gets to 50, it'll reach frame 50, and so on.

Is this the correct way of going about this?

Thanks.

---

Here are the variables being used in the code I'm trying to fix below. Also, the game I'm creating has multiple characters, so the bar  I'm referring to is within a couple of movieclips.

Basically, when the character double jumps, it is flying, and the bar depletes. Once the bars depletes to 0(Or when PercentHP is 0) then it should end the flying. Afterwards, I would like the bar to fill back up towards 100 overtime.

```
var percentHP = Number(Bar.CBar.CMana_bar.currentFrame) / Number(100);
var gravityConstant:Number = 1;   
var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
var flyingJump:Boolean = false;
var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

function loop(e:Event):void{
    //Flying
            if(upReleasedInAir == true){ // if the player releases the up arrow key
                upReleasedInAir = false; // set the variable to true
            }
            if(doubleJumpReady == false){
                doubleJumpReady = true;
            }
        } else { //if we are not touching the floor

            ySpeed += gravityConstant; //accelerate downwards

            //Flying
            if(upPressed == false && upReleasedInAir == false){
                upReleasedInAir = true;
                //trace("upReleasedInAir");
            }
            if(doubleJumpReady && upReleasedInAir){
                if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
                    flyingJump = true;
                    //trace("doubleJump!");
                    doubleJumpReady = false;
                    ySpeed = jumpConstant + 8; //set the y speed to the jump constant
                    gravityConstant = 0;
                    Bar.CBar.CMana_bar.play();
                    //trace(percentMP);
                }
                }
                if(Bar.CBar.CMana_bar.currentFrame == 100 && percentHP == 0){
            gravityConstant = 1;
            Bar.CBar.CMana_bar.stop();
            flyingJump = false;
            doubleJumpReady = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is attach a MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP event to your button. Type in `stop();` in frame 1 of your bar and then use MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP to play or stop the animation in your bar. Something along the lines of:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
function mouseDownHandler(e:Event):void{
bar.play();
} 
function mouseUpHandler(e:Event):void{
bar.stop();
percentHP = Number(bar.currentFrame) / Number(100); //If you still need to know the percent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I change the percentHP var to make it equal bar.currentFrame? I think the problem I am having now is that percentHP is equaling two different things. The code you have makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: I get the dreaded error 1009 whenever I try to have a var equal a currentFrame.

Comment: @Bindlestick Check your stack trace and make sure that the Null Reference error is actually from the same line as the currentFrame call. If it is then play() and stop() should also throw the same error. Also, try tracing Bar.CBar.CMana_bar like `trace(Bar); trace(Bar.CBar); trace(Bar.CBar.CMana_bar)` and see what it says. Make sure none of them were set to null anywhere in your code.

Comment: alright. Well I commented out the currentFrame code to trace the trace(Bar.CBar). That is coming off as null, however, what I did was put a stop(); on the first frame of the bar so that it stops. When I press up, it plays and the bar goes all the way down. So it works, but the currentFrame code doesn't. What's my next step after finding out where the null is coming from?

Comment: @Bindlestick A null object means that it is either defined and not initialized or explicitly set to null somewhere in the code. If the MovieClip were undefined, you would be getting error 1010. So, the next step is to check your code and FLA to see why Bar.CBar is null.

Answer (score 0):

If your asking how to reach a frame by its number, use the `MovieClip.gotoAndStop` method :

```
loaderBar.gotoAndStop(percentHP);
```